# Add name for each item in an object C#

Tags: c#

I run from stored procedure and use sqlDataReader reader to read it then I have a object[] result that writes all data in. The data looks like this:

```
 result:  { {[0],[1],[2]},{[0],[1],[2]},{[0],[1],[2]},{[0],[1],[2]},{[0],[1],[2]},{[0],[1],[2]}, ... }
```

A real example would be like `{{1,{1/18/2017},20},{2,{1/19/2017},21},{3,{1/20/2017},22}}`

I want to add item name for each item in each child object and return json to my javascript. So expected result would be:

```
result = {{"ID":1, "Date":{1/18/2017},"value":20},
          {"ID":2,"Date":{1/19/2017},"value":21},
          {"ID":3,"Date":{1/20/2017},"value":22}}
```

Anyone knows the proper way to do it? Using LinqtoObject or lambda or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd suggest.  Create a struct:

```
struct MyThing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then initialize your list like this:

```
var input = new List<MyThing>(new[] 
{ 
    new MyThing { ID = 1, Date = DateTime.Parse("1/18/2017"), Value = 20 }, 
    new MyThing { ID = 2, Date = DateTime.Parse("1/19/2017"), Value = 21 }, 
    new MyThing { ID = 3, Date = DateTime.Parse("1/20/2017"), Value = 22 } 
});
```

.NET is an object oriented language, so take advantage of that, i.e. create classes or, in this case, structs, to hold common sets of information.

Also, it's a lot easier to work with lists than arrays.

As for converting to JSON, I'm not an expert, but here's what I threw together for the above code:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonText = serializer.Serialize(input);
```

Note, you will need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` and add a `using` directive:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Comment: It sounds like OP is asking for a way to automate this process, instead of `new`ing the objects up manually.